# Creating table out from this array structure in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im having trouble creating a table out from this array:

http://pastebin.com/DXFjfhHJ

I started out with this:

```
<table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <tr>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Aktivitet</td>
        <td>Duration</td>
        <td>Metabolisation</td>
   </tr>
```

then i did:

```
foreach{$training as $time => $metabolisation}{
?>
                <tr style="text-align: left;">
                    <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
                    <td>Activity name</td>
                    <td>Duration</td>
                    <td><?php echo $metabolisation; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php
 }
```

Which works almost.. It shows the right $time ( 03:00 etc. ), but nothing in $metabolisation. And I dont know how to call the Activity, it should be the arrays "name" variable. Same with duration, it should be the arrays "duration"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the structure your using in your pastebin is not compatible with your foreach. You realy need to look deeper in your array structure like this.

```
<?php foreach( $training as $time => $data ): ?>
  <tr style="text-align: left;">
    <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
    <td>Total <?php echo $data['entries'][0]['name']; ?></td>
    <td>Duration <?php echo $data['entries'][0]['duration']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['entries'][0]['metabolisation']; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($training as $time => $metabolisation){
  foreach($metabolisation['entries'] as $entry) {
?>

<tr style="text-align: left;">
  <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $entry['name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $entry['duartion']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $entry['metabolisation']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
  }
}
?>
```

It probably doesn't output the data in an appropriate form, but you get the idea how to access it.